# Django pre fill a form with data from a selected line in a table

Tags: python, django, forms

This site has been of great help but now I'm stuck.
I have a page (allrmview) where the user can filter a table. Once that is done he can select a line. It opens a form (NewrmForm) page which is pre filled with some informations from the selected line in the table. I don't understand how i can send the datas selected to the new form. As I am a beginner a lot of elements are missing.

models.py:

```
class Infomp(models.Model):
    url = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=37, blank=True, null=True)
    synonyme = models.CharField(max_length=126, blank=True, null=True)
    chemname = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    cas = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
    einecs = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
    mweight = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    vappress = models.CharField(max_length=31, blank=True, null=True)
    solublein = models.CharField(max_length=89, blank=True, null=True)
    insoluble = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True, null=True)
    odortype = models.CharField(max_length=11, blank=True, null=True)
    odorstrength = models.CharField(max_length=55, blank=True, null=True)
    substantivity = models.CharField(max_length=44, blank=True, null=True)
    odordescript1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    odordescript2 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    usagelevel = models.CharField(max_length=39, blank=True, null=True)
    ifra = models.CharField(max_length=24, blank=True, null=True)
    risk = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    cosing = models.CharField(max_length=6, blank=True, null=True)

class RmStock(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')
    num = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    n_tgsc = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    nom_mp = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    quantite = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    fournisseur = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    cert_ifra = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    tds = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    msds = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    od_strength = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    od_type = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    od_descr = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    n_cas = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    subst = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    kindofm = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=False, default='4')
    n_mp = models.SmallIntegerField()
    r_fourn = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import RmStock

class NewrmForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = RmStock
        fields = [
            'nom_mp',
            'n_cas',
            'fournisseur',
            'num'
            ]
```

I suppose it's in the addnew-view that I have to make the variables correspond. But hot to tell that some fields correspond to the fields from the previous table. More explicit how can i write that 
 nom_mp = infomp.name
n_cas=infomp.cas

views.py:

```
def allmaterial_search_view(request):
    rms = Infomp.objects.all()
    name_synonyme_chemname_query = request.GET.get('name_synonyme_chemname')

    if name_synonyme_chemname_query !='' and name_synonyme_chemname_query is not None:
        rms = rms.filter (Q(name__icontains=name_synonyme_chemname_query) | Q(synonyme__icontains=name_synonyme_chemname_query)).distinct()
    context = {
        'queryset': rms
    }
    return render(request,'rawmaterials/allrmview.html', context)

def addnewrm_view(request):
    form = NewrmForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()

    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request,'rawmaterials/addnewrm.html', context)
```

making a POST on the form here is maybe the way but not written like this I guess. 

allrmview.html

```
{% extends "app/layout.html" %}

{% block content %}
<form>
<div class="container">
    <input class="" type="search" name="name_synonyme_chemname" placeholder="Enter name" value="">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
</div>
</form>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md" style="margin-left:5%;margin-right:5%";>
        <div class="card card-body">
            <h5>All Raw Materials</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="card card-body">
            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <th>Nom</th>
                    <th>Synonyme</th>
                    <th>CAS</th>
                </tr>
               
                {% for infomp in queryset %}
                <tr>
                    <form action='/add_rm_to_myrm/'' method="post" id="addrmForm">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                    <td>{{infomp.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{infomp.synonyme}}</td>
                    <td>{{infomp.cas}}</td>
                    <td>{{infomp.pk}}</td>
                    
                    <td>
                        <button type="submit" name="addrm_b" value="try" class="btn btn-primary">+</button>
                        <a class="btn btn-primary" target="_blank" href="/rawmaterials">+</a>
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

addnewrm.html

```
{% extends "app/layout.html" %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <form>{{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">validate</button>    
    </form>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

url.py

```
 path('allrmview/', allmaterial_search_view),
    path('add_rm_to_myrm/', addnewrm_view)
```

I hope I have been clear enough and sorry being a noob but i have to start somewhere. Maybe initial or instance is the solution but I have no idea how to place that.

**EDIT** So it gets a lot better but still stuck on a little thing.

This piece of code does not work :

```
form = NewrmForm(request.POST or None,initial=initial_dict)
```

I tried this but not better :

```
form = NewrmForm(initial=initial_dict)
if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewrmForm(request.POST or None)
```

If I don't put the initial in place of the request, the form is pre filled but than of course it does not send the form to the database.
Like written, it works the the fields are not pre filled.
Any clue?
Here is the entire code :

views.py

```
def allmaterial_search_view(request):
    rms = Infomp.objects.all()
    name_synonyme_chemname_query = request.GET.get('name_synonyme_chemname')

    if name_synonyme_chemname_query !='' and name_synonyme_chemname_query is not None:
        rms = rms.filter (Q(name__icontains=name_synonyme_chemname_query) | Q(synonyme__icontains=name_synonyme_chemname_query)).distinct()
    context = {
        'queryset': rms
    }
    return render(request,'rawmaterials/allrmview.html', context)

def addnewrm_view(request, id):
    infomp=Infomp.objects.get(id=id)
    lastnum = RmStock.objects.all().order_by('num').last().num
    lastnum1 = lastnum+1
    initial_dict = {'nom_mp': infomp.name, 'num':lastnum1}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewrmForm(request.POST or None,initial=initial_dict)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()  
            return redirect("/")  
    else:  
        form = NewrmForm()
  
    context = {'form':form,
                'infomp':infomp
         }    
    return render(request,'rawmaterials/addnewrm.html', context)
```

allrmview.py:

```
{% extends "app/layout.html" %}

{% block content %}
<form>
<div class="container">
    <input class="" type="search" name="name_synonyme_chemname" placeholder="Enter name" value="">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
</div>
</form>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md" style="margin-left:5%;margin-right:5%";>
        <div class="card card-body">
            <h5>All Raw Materials</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="card card-body">
            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <th>Nom</th>
                    <th>Synonyme</th>
                    <th>CAS</th>
                </tr>
               
                {% for infomp in queryset %}
                <tr>
                    <form action='/add_rm_to_myrm/{{ infomp.id }}' method="post" id="addrmForm">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                    <td>{{infomp.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{infomp.synonyme}}</td>
                    <td>{{infomp.cas}}</td>
                    
                    <td>
                        <button type="submit" name="addrm_b" value="try" class="btn btn-primary">+</button>
                        <a class="btn btn-primary" target="_blank" href="/add_rm_to_myrm/{{ infomp.id }}">+</a>
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}

<input class="" type="search" name="name_synonyme_chemname" placeholder="Enter name" value="">
```

addnewrm.py

```
{% extends "app/layout.html" %}


{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <form method="POST" >
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">validate</button>    
    </form>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```